# Не работает тег video

Tags: html, css, html5

Пробую добавить видео но его не отражает
Пробовал по разному, возможно нужно добавить специальные настройки?

```
<video preload="false" loop="true" muted="muted" controls>
    <source src="../src/img/blow/test.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ошибка в пути к видео, вы уверены что с вашего домена можно получить доступ к этому видео? попробуйте просто открыть его в отдельной вкладке.

Comment: тоже не работает, видео рабочие, не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: Возможно ошибка в пути к видео, вы уверены что с вашего домена можно получить доступ к этому видео? попробуйте просто открыть его в отдельной вкладке.

Comment: спасибо! Посмотрел и действительно проблема была в пути...